# BIND zone file error

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind, dns-zone

Im having an issue with a zone file in BIND.

Here is the zone file, private information is masked.

```
$ORIGIN xx.com.
$TTL 60

@                       IN SOA  ns01.xx.com. hostmaster.xx.com. (
                            2019040702   ; serial number DATE PLUS SEQUENCENR
                            3600       ; refresh (15 minutes)
                            3600       ; retry (10 minutes)
                            86400      ; expire (1 day)
                            3600       ; minimum (1 hour)
                            )

                    NS      ns01.xx.com.
                    NS      ns02.xx.com.

; Mail-servers
@                       MX      10      ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@                       MX      20      ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@                       MX      20      ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@                       MX      30      ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@                       MX      30      ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.

@                       A       1.2.3.4
www                     A       1.2.3.4
```

Whenever i run named-checkconf xx.com i get this error:

```
xx.com:1: unknown option '$ORIGIN'
xx.com:5: unknown option 'serial'
xx.com:6: unknown option 'refresh'
xx.com:7: unknown option 'retry'
xx.com:8: unknown option 'expire'
xx.com:9: unknown option 'minimum'
xx.com:15: unknown option 'Mail-servers'
xx.com:24: unexpected token near end of file
```

And then BIND doesnt start up.

Anyone see any issues with this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it name implies `named-checkconf` is to check Bind **configuration** files, not zonefiles!

To check zonefiles you need to use `named-checkzone`

It will let you know that your zone has a problem because your in-bailiwick nameservers have no `A` nor `AAAA` records.

PS: do not obfuscate things so badly, `1.2.3.4` and `xx.com` are valid global public identifiers that exist today and are not yours. There are guidelines to obfuscation, look at RFC2606 and RFC5737